# Question about Radio button/PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I'm an engineering student and I'm developing a simple software based on HTML, PHP and mysql. I learned this topics on w3schools. I know only the basics. I tried to search about this in this website but I found questions about PHP, MySQL and HTML radio buttons which were much more complex than I need and that I could understand. Sorry for the English.

(Q1) Ex: `$email=$_REQUEST['email']` , in this case the input is text, if it were like a radio button for ex: sex: male or female, how would it be?

(Q2) what would be the type of this field (for example sex in question 1) in the database: text, int, varchar ?

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the html:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="M" />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="F" />
```

In PHP you would get the value from `$_REQUEST['sex']`, which would give you either `M` or `F`, depending on which radio was checked.

A database column to go with this would have the type `varchar(1)`

You could, of course, use integers as well, just be careful when choosing which value the females get (they tend to prefer the higher one).

Comment: Great comment on the value of females.